# Is it possible to create a report (type) for custom metadata?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, custom-metadata

Custom metadata (types) looks like a cool feature. I have created dozens of instances of one that I made and now I would like to create a report on them, because a list view is not good enough.

So first I need to create a report type for this, as the type is not available when creating a report, but my custom metadata type is not in the list of objects for which I can make a report type.

When creating or modifying the custom metadata type, it says "The singular and plural labels are used in tabs, page layouts, and **reports**."

This suggests that it is possible to create a report. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reports documentation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232338/is-it-possible-to-create-a-report-type-for-custom-metadata) states that

> Reports give you access to your Salesforce data

While [`Custom Metadata`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=5) is not considered as data

> You can create your own declarative developer frameworks for internal
>   teams, partners, and customers. Rather than building apps from data,
>   you can build apps that are defined and driven by their **own types** of
>   **metadata**. `Metadata` is the information that describes the configuration
>   of each customer’s organization.

Emphasis on `metadata` is mine in the quote. So basically it is not possible to create report on `Custom metadata` since reports can be created from data, while `Custom metadata` is not considered as data, but rather as metadata.

When we read about [creation of custom report type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm&type=5), we can find references to two of three types of objects.

> If the primary object on a report type is a **custom** or **external** object,
>   and that object is deleted, the report type and reports created from
>   it are deleted.

Emphasis on  **custom** or **external** object is mine.

So, reports are not available not only to `custom metadata` or `custom settings` but even for big objects despite they are actually data.

Answer (score 0):

If you install salesforce CLI, using the command to retrieve the custom metadata file by its mdt name... "sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:[metadatatypename]_mdt -u [username]" ... will give you a directory list in the sfdc project on your hard drive. From there you can export the directory using dos commands to excel to get a rudimentary list into usable format.